# Duplicate Fancybox overlay div - why?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using the Fancybox to display the target of a link in the fancybox. This is my code to register the box:

```
jQuery(".popup").fancybox({
    'width'         : 900,
    'height'        : '95%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'          : 'iframe'
});
```

Now the link with the popup class:

```
<a href="link to the site that should be shown" class="popup">link text</a>
```

Clicking this link will copy the content of the link to the fancybox div which looks like this:

```
<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block;">content goes here</div>
```

Now, my problem is, that I have 2 of those divs, one with the content and an empty one. This breaks the layout. Any ideas, how this can be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have 2 of those divs? Can't you use the content div that fancybox creates?

Comment: Thats the question! I can see the div with the content, but the second one overlays it completely. It seems that fancybox appends the div twice.

Comment: The content doesn't go in `fancybox-overlay`, it goes in `fancybox-content`. The overlay div is for the grey background so it sounds like something is up there. Can you post a URL to a demo of your page?

Comment: Unfortunalety I cant post a URL.

Comment: you can't have two `div` with content since you are using `iframe` type. Fancybox adds a `div` to your document, which actually contains the `iframe` where your targeted page is opened.

Comment: I know I cant have 2 divs. I dont add them myself, they get added by fancybox. The question is, why.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem. Found out reason why div duplications happen to me. the content that was loaded for me in fancybox was loading a layout with fancybox asset (in rails)
so it scrambled everything up.

in the action i wanted to render writing:

```
render layout: false
```

did the trick.

This is an old question but maybe it will be of use for someone.